# maven, get execution id of goal at runtime in mojo execute()?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

Is there a way to get the current execution id of a goal at runtime from the mojo implementation?

I would like to use the execution id in the mojo code to avoid the need for an extra configuration parameter.

Here is an execution example:

```xml
<execution>
  <id>spring</id>
  <phase>generate-sources</phase>

  <configuration>
    <id>spring</id>  <!-- duplicate.. -->
    <apiPath>${project.basedir}/src/api/openapi.yaml</apiPath>
  </configuration>
           
  <goals>
    <goal>process</goal>
  </goals>
</execution>
```

Depending on the value of `<id>` the `process` mojo would run different code. I need the id to select the correct service (loaded with `java.util.ServiceLoader`).

Not sure if reusing the id is a good idea but I would like to know if it is possible at all? :-)

Comment: That means you want to couple the execution id to a configuration ? Sounds like a very bad idea...

Comment: That sounds like a method that behaves differently when you rename the parameter.

Comment: sure, not the best idea, but is it possible? ;-)

Comment: Why should anybody spend time to figure out a way if it's a bad idea? Furthermore, even if I knew, I would not write an answer. Other people might find it and think that is a good approach.

Comment: I just asked a question out of curiosity. If you don't like it, please ignore it. There is no reason to write an unfriendly comment.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer to my question in the `AbstractCompilerMojo.java` class of the maven-compiler-plugin. It declares the following `@Parameter`

```java
@Parameter( defaultValue = "${mojoExecution}", readonly = true, required = true )
private MojoExecution mojoExecution;
```

The `MojoExecution` contains the execution id.

> I do not recommend the original motivation of my question: to use the execution id for plugin internal logic.
>
> It is usually not a good idea to re-use details like this for another purpose and apply a **second meaning** to an existing information. It is confusing and unexpected for someone not aware of it.

It's still a valuable piece of information, because the `defaultValue` of the `@Parameter` annotation allows other expressions that can be used by a plugin to access information about the project & the build.